# Making FatFS filesystem on STM32 available to PC over ESP8266 WiFi

Tags: stm32, esp8266, fileserver

I am in the very early stage of getting my head around about how to access a FatFS filesystem.

Setup:

- STM with SD card slot and FatFS installed.
- ESP8266 with AT firmware connected to serial port of STM
- ESP8266 prepared to connect to a WiFi router (or provides AP) and to open a TCP connection to a remote TCP Server

Use case:

- User at PC connected to the same WiFi network or to the ESP as AP
- User accesses SD card on STM to list directories, read/write/copy/delete files

My ideas so far:

- implement FTP Server (that can access the SD card) on STM. User on PC
  connects with FTP client
- implement WebDAV Server (that can access the SD card) on STM. User on
  PC connects with (builtin) WebDAV client
- implement some sort of HTTP Server that accesses the SD Card on STM.
  No idea about a nice and user friendly client

Most likely not the best ideas. Can someone please point me in the right direction. Basically are there any off-the-shelf solutions to the idea of having a file server on an embedded system and accessing the file server over a ESP8266 provided TCP connection?

Your assistance is very much appreciated

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: https://github.com/jandrassy/WiFiEspAT/blob/master/examples/Advanced/SDWebServer/SDWebServer.ino

Comment: you can use STM32 as Arduino with the https://github.com/stm32duino/Arduino_Core_STM32

Comment: Juraj, many thanks for your reply. STM32 run freeRTOS but that doesn't really matter for the basic concept. The hw setup in the example you posted is exactly what I am trying to do, also using AT commands. I'll dig into this example. I'd have to replace the SD Card handling to using FatFS which shouldn't be very difficult.